# My post permalinks are always the same

Tags: posts, permalinks, slug

I noticed all my new posts have the same permalink. I noticed it was the same as my sticky post so I removed that setting but it didn't change anything. If I create a post called "Permalink Test" I would expect my url to be like `/blog/permalink-test` but instead it the permalink for another post.

I tried resetting my permalinks in the settings but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: If I manually change it after it's wrong, it takes the change.

Comment: the view link is incorrect on the admin screen? or the permalinks are incorrect on the front end?